# IndexMissingException while creating index in elasticsaerch

Tags: java, indexing, elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. I have tried CRUD processes of elasticsearch in Curl Api. But no I want to write my java code which is following:

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args){


    Node node = nodeBuilder().local(true).clusterName("myclustername").node();
    Client client = node.client();

    try {
        IndexResponse indexResponse = client
                .prepareIndex("company", "employee", "367")
                .setSource(
                        jsonBuilder()
                                .startObject()
                                .field("name", "surendra")
                                .field("address", "kapan")
                                .endObject()
                )
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

The code ran successfully with no error. But when I send Get request it sends IndexMissingException. I have double checked my cluster name.
What is wrong here?

Comment: Could you show how you build your get request?

Comment: curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/company/employee/1

Comment: I was success on inserting data with same index and type but different id. But did not get with result with this id while running from my java program. The cluster health is yellow

Comment: I suspect you are indexing and querying on different clusters. Are you using the same cluster name in your cluster conf and java code? Why do you use a local node?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I just saw the difference so thought that I should ask you.

You are inserting the recors with ID=367 in your Java Code.
But while retriving you are executing it for ID=1

curl -XGET localhost:9200/company/employee/1

Try following Command:
curl -XGET localhost:9200/company/employee/367

You can also try inserting the record using curl command and try to retrive it.

Regards,
Jayesh Bhoyar

Comment: You can try head plugin to check whether the record is getting inserted in your index or not.